# inquiry about Transaction

Tags: transactions

I sent `0.027 BTC` over a day ago with the transaction number `254d1352749e9a18effecbd6d340479d75ca4500e2da8eda1a77f51634ee3f6f`

The person i sent to still says, they have not received anything yet the transaction says in my wallet it is confirmed.

What could be the problem?

Comment: his btc：18eCjf3zWajVvSE9AqEXJt9CaGe7oD6ohJ

Answer (score 1):

Transaction was succesful. I just verified in blockexplorer https://blockexplorer.com/tx/254d1352749e9a18effecbd6d340479d75ca4500e2da8eda1a77f51634ee3f6f

Make sure you sent this to the correct address. If yes, then ask the recipient to check in a blockexplorer. That's enough.

Answer (score 1):

Same news on [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/tx/254d1352749e9a18effecbd6d340479d75ca4500e2da8eda1a77f51634ee3f6f) - not only is the transaction confirmed but, it is also spent so it is most certainly received.